# How to add a gif file to my LaTeX file?

Tags: graphics, gif

> **Related:**
>   [Convert gif image to png on the fly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/convert-gif-image-to-png-on-the-fly)

I have an image file -- a gif file, which is the graph of a function.
How do I add it to a LaTeX file? Will it come out OK in the subsequent pdf file?

Answer (score 85):

Use `movie15` package. For example:

```
% in preamble
\usepackage{movie15}
% in documenet
\includemovie{1cm}{1cm}{ani.gif}
```

PDFLaTeX is needed, and you must use Adobe Reader with certain media player plug-in. Thus it often fails.

Another method is to use `animate` package. You have to convert the animated gif to separate images first, using ImageMagick:

```
convert foo.gif foo.png
```

This would sometimes create a suboptimal result; if the GIF is optimized try

```
convert foo.gif -coalesce foo.png
```

You may probably get `foo-0.png`, `foo-1.png`, ..., `foo-18.png`.

Then include the graphics:

```
\animategraphics{12}{foo-}{0}{18}
```

See the manual of `animate` for more options.

Comment: Interesting, but the OP didn't request animation ... `:-)`

Comment: Indeed. I noticed @TeX asked for animated GIF, so I appended this answer.

Comment: I tried with different (animated) gif and none shows up in the PDF (Acrobat viewer), can any one point to a sample gif that works with movie15?

Comment: The original question doesn't mention animated gifs.  The workflow for including animated gifs as opposed to plain gifs is so significantly different that I think this answer isn't helpful to the question.

Comment: I got the error `! Package movie15 Error: File 'test.gif' cannot be opened for embeddin`

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: I think there have been some updates since this post was last edited and now we need to use `magick` instead of `convert`. So, we should now use `magick foo.gif -coalesce foo.png`

Answer (score 18):

needs `pdflatex -shell-escape ...` and an installed program `convert` which is available for all plarforms

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{convert gif:#1 png:\OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}

\begin{document}

  \includegraphics{demo.eps}\qquad
  \includegraphics{knuth-tex.gif}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, animation in the original gif will no longer work after conversion.

Comment: And some people use LaTeX (Beamer) for presentation slides, so animation is useful.

Answer (score 14):

With the original `latex` engine, this would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{your.gif}
\end{document}
```

But if you are using `pdflatex` or `xelatex`, this will result in an error about `.gif` being an unknown graphics extension.  (If you don't know which engine you are using, it's probably `pdflatex`.)  I would recommend converting the `.gif` file to a `.png` file and repeating the above snippet, with `your.gif` replaced by `your.png`.  In fact, you can just use `your`; latex has a default set of extensions it will add to find the file.

There are dozens of ways to convert GIFs to PNGs, including many free online services. Google is your friend.  The only reason I can see to convert the file on the fly with each compiling of the latex document would be if your gif file changes often as the result of some other process.

Comment: Even with the package graphicx I still get errors about the unknown graphics extension .gif. For me this doesn't work

Comment: @JorisMeys.  Are you using `pdflatex` or `xelatex` to compile?  If so, read the second sentence.  You'll need to convert the graphic to `.png` some other way before including in a TeX document.

Comment: Stupid oversight, thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @JorisMeys: I rewrote the answer to highlight the difference the engine makes in how to approach this problem.

Comment: But if you convert to png then the animation effect is lost?

Comment: @Nulle Well yeah, most of the time you don't want an animated gif in a PDF document.  If you do, take a look at the [`animate`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/animate/animate.pdf) package.

Answer (score 1):

If you wese using windows, you could just right click the .gif file and "open with" MS-Paint

Then just save the file as .jpg one and use it like you please.

Comment: GIF is a lossless compressed bitmap format and JPG is lossy. Better convert it to PNG.

Comment: This will not work when you have to show an animation using animated gif.