# How to achieve a rotating figure animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I have a figure, in `*.eps`, say a pentagon which is already drawn and then included in TeX, and I want to achieve a rotating animation. So the polygon will be rotating about some point (usually its center) at some rate.   How is this done?

Comment: I'm not sure if latex supports animation.  Someone who knows better than I will probably come along soon to confirm or deny.  I suspect you may have to make a gif and include that as in this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10381/14100

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The topic poster seems to want a *single* graphic file to be rotated around its centre. In that case, `animateinline` environment may be the better choice, as the image file is included only once (at least in case of pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX/dvipdfmx), which saves file size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength\imgwd
\setlength\imgwd{2in}
\newlength\imght
\setlength\imght{2in}
\newlength\imgdiag
\setlength\imgdiag{1.4142\imgwd} %should be set to sqrt(imgwd^2+imght^2)

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{12}
\multiframe{36}{iAng=0+10}{%
  \makebox[\imgdiag][c]{%
    \rule[-0.5\imgdiag]{0pt}{\imgdiag}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{\iAng}{%
      \raisebox{-0.5\height}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\imgwd,height=\imght]{tiger}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The [`animate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/animate) allows you to do this by supplying a number of images with some base name. The default format is:

```
\animategraphics[<options>]{<frame rate>}{<base filename>}{<start>}{<finish>}
```

There are some examples of [animations in TeX using TikZ on TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/).

Comment: I have to open the output pdf in Acrobat to see the animation in a Mac.  It does not work under preview.  People who use Macs do not like this.  Therefore, I usually do not include movies and animations.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I have had quite a bit of trouble using animated graphics or much of any interactivity, which apparently uses JavaScript, on anything other than Adobe on PC or Mac. Even Adobe Reader version for tablets does not work for such cases.

Answer (score 9):

Here a simple example. I created a list of figures. In your case, if you have a defined picture, you can make a rotation with a `\foreach` to get the same thing.

`animateinline` environment is a fine alternativ in AlexG'answer

**Update**

**Step one** : Create the pentagon

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node  [draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=4cm,outer sep=0pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Step two** : the list of pictures in pentagon.pdf with pentagon.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview} 
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} 
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}% 
\begin{document} 
\foreach \a in {0,5,...,360}{% 
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3) ;
    \node[rotate=\a,transform shape] {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{aPentagon}};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

**Step three** : the final pdf with animate

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{animate} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{center} 
\animategraphics[palindrome]{12}{pentagon}{}{} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I try `animateinline` with success to avoid the last two steps but I don't know the options to   get a fine result.

The problem here is to get an animated gif because the pdf seems to be wrong.

---

**First try**

**Step 1**

You create a list of pictures. I used beamer and I have a correct size for the pictures. I named `triangle.tex` the source

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview} 
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} 
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}% 
\begin{document} 

  \newcommand\setC{%
   \pgfmathsetmacro\Cx{5-3*cos(\alpha)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\Cy{3*sin(\alpha)}
   \fill [blue] (\Cx,\Cy) circle (2pt);
   }%

\foreach \a in {0,10,...,180}{% 
   \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (9,5);
    \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);
    \fill[blue] (4,0) circle (2pt);
    \setC
    \draw (0,0)--(4,0)--(\Cx,\Cy)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture} 
 }

\end{document}
```

**Step 2**

I created a new little file `animated_triangle.tex`. The important line is

```
 \animategraphics[palindrome]{12}{triangle}{}{}
```

**palindrome** is an option of the animate package (see the doc), 12 number of frames per second (I think ...), **triangle** is the name of the pdf with the list of pictures. The last two arguments are for the first picture of the animation and the last. Here I use all the pictures.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{animate} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Produit Scalaire} 
\begin{center} 
\animategraphics[palindrome]{12}{tranim}{}{} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I don't know how to place an animated gif on tex.se, I placed the  pdf . With the help of Peter and the explanations of Martin, I get an animated gif but there are some little problems.
A first result is :

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to create an animate gif. I saw some examples on the tex.se. If someone can replace my pdf file with an animated gif, I will be happy !

Comment: Have a look at the link in my answer to the Sieve of Eratosthenes to an Answer Martin Scharrer provided which uses `pdfcrop` and ImageMagick's `convert` to generates a gif

Comment: Why did you use a two-step method instead of directly putting the parametric `tikzpicture` into a `\multiframe` command inside an `animateinline` environment?

Comment: I don't know the `animateinline environment`and I always made like this but I need to look at your example. It's very possible that your method is better

Comment: Just in case anyone else struggled to find the link mentioned in the comments! The answer by Martin Scharrer that Peter Grill is referring to is in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23727/converting-beamer-slides-to-animated-images

Comment: But I think anybody seeking that linke may also be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73545/how-to-convert-pstricks-animation-to-gif-file