# The file does not conform to Adobe's published PDF?

Tags: pdftex

My question is how to check if a pdf file created with pdfTeX-1.40.12 is conform to Adobe's published PDF ? Is it possible to know ?

I try to look at the properties of the file with Adobe Reader but I see nothing.

This problem appears when I try to get a gif file from a pdf file with `convert`

I get this message :

> ```
> Warning:  Default viewing OC config dictionary has /BaseState /OFF
>
> This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
>
> The file was produced by:  pdfTeX-1.40.12 
> Please notify the author of the software that produced this
> file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
> specification.
> ```

Perhaps it's a problem with `convert` but independently, how to know if a pdf is conform to the norm. I think that the fact to be able to open a pdf with a viewer is not a proof.

The pdf is get with the first example of my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55209/how-to-achieve-a-rotating-figure-animation). The pdf with the pentagon.
I used `convert` like this (Martin's idea)

```
convert -verbose -delay 100 -loop 0 -density 400 namefile.pdf namefile.gif
```

Comment: We are going to need to know about the PDF in question, in particular any multimedia or graphics inclusions.

Comment: @JosephWright I put the link to get the sources of the file. I show two examples and I used the same methods, except that in the first example, I used `\includegraphics`. My question is not exactly to get a fine gif file but a method to analyze a pdf file and to know what is wrong. Do you know a tool to verify a pdf ? perhaps it's impossible ?

Comment: @Altermundus: Sorry, can not reproduce. We need the pdf.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I put the pdf here http://altermundus.com/SandBox/pentagon.pdf now the error has changed. I get PDF 1000x1000 1000x1000+0+0 16-bit PaletteBilevelMatte PseudoClass 2c 311KB 24.570u 0:24.720
convert: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/589.

Comment: @Altermundus: The PDF looks o.k. to me. I suggest you file a bug with the ImageMagick developers.

Comment: @MartinSchröder ok thanks for the information

Comment: Related Question: [PDF compatibility, how to validate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/pdf-compatibility-how-to-validate)