# PDF compatibility, how to validate?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF conformance tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33280/pdf-conformance-tool)

I have created PDF-files using XeLaTeX and there has been no problem when I have shared these files with co-workers using Acrobat Reader. But when I tried to upload these files to a special www-based form, I received an error message that basically claimed that my PDF-files were no real PDF-files. Later I checked the beginning of the files and they began with %PDF-1.5 which I believe is according to the standard.

My main question is how I can use XeLaTeX or PDFLaTeX to generate PDF-files compliant to the standard and not causing errors?

Minor followupquestions:
Can XeLaTeX and/or pdfLaTeX generate PDF-files compliant to the standard? 
Any thoughts on what caused my problem? 
How to check validate a PDF-file?
How to circumvent compatibility issues?

**UPDATE**

I made some extensive testing and found that the www-based form that received my files in general has no problem with PDF-files generated using XeTeX or pdfTeX. This was what I expected from the start since I believed that XeTeX and pdfTeX followed the open PDF-standard (ISO).

My root cause of my problem described above was a particular EPS-file that was included when producing my PDF-files. Other EPS-files does not cause problem when used with TeX. If the problematic EPS-file is inserted in an ODT-document using LibreOffice and a PDF-file is exported, there is no problem with the PDF-file.

*Thus, I have found a compatibility problem between XeTeX/pdfTeX and a particular EPS-file. Any thoughts on how to check for compatibility between EPS and XeTeX/pdfTeX, and how to circumvent problems?*

Comment: Related Question: [The file does not conform to Adobe's published PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55255/the-file-does-not-conform-to-adobes-published-pdf).  Even though this question has been closed I think it would be helpful to have some sort of tool that confirms that the file compiles with a standard -- just the fact that it opens in a particular PDF reader does not meant hat it will necessarily open with other PDF readers.

Comment: Convert your eps files to pdf using a higher version compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

All PDF producing TeX engines (pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX) typically produce [standard-compliant](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) PDFs - iff the standard is ISO 32000-1:2008. Ofther PDF standards like [PDF/X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/X) or [PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) are also somewhat possible.

Comment: Thanks @martin-schroder. Please see my update to the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: @mghg: pdfTeX doesn't handle eps natively: they must be converted (TeXLive now does this automagically).

Answer (score 3):

pdfx package can help you generate pdf/x-1a or pdf/a-1b compliant documents using pdfLaTeX. This could be one of the formats expected. pdfx.sty is incompatible with XeLaTeX. Acrobat professional version is needed to check the pdf generated.