# How to draw a sine wave on a circular path in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw circular waves like [these](http://thisquantumworld.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/deBroglie-1024x361.png):

[image]

in TikZ.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Well to start off with, it would be helpful if you figured out the equation(s) to that represents that path you want to draw -- that is a math issue, not a TeX issue. Once you get that (perhaps in parametrized form), the I'd suggest you use `pgfplots` pacakge to draw it.  There should be plenty of examples on this site for that. Once you make an attempt and run into a specific issue, then perhaps you can update this question showing what you attempted, and then people here could help you with a specific issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'll draw the first one and you try to work on the rest. You can do this iteratively, too, I think, with some extra work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,very thick]
\draw[color=red,domain=0:6.28,samples=200,smooth] plot (canvas polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius={28-8*sin(3*\x r)});
\draw[,dashed,domain=0:6.28,samples=200,smooth] plot (canvas polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius={0.5 r});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As have been said in the comment above, once you have the mathematical equation in polar coordinates, it is just a matter of some `pgfplots` work. To learn more about `pgplots`, which is built upon `tikz`, type `texdoc pgfplots` in your terminal.

### Edit

This is *not* a `pgfplots` solution BTW. As have been noted by Paul Gaborit in comment, `pgfplots` is superfluous in the given code. I was about to go back to it since I mentioned `pgfplots` in my answer. I've been away for a while. Anyway, others have already provided other solutions so I will leave my answer as it is.

Comment: `\usepackage{pgfplots}` is superfluous...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yeah. Removed it. I was working with `article` class before replacing it with `standalone`. And I was thinking of `pgfplots` solution earlier. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Adding `border=10` to the options to the `standalone` class can help when the clipping is overzealous.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks. I will update picture tomorrow when I am on a proper computer.

Comment: No rush!  Just thought it a useful option to know about.

Comment: @hpesoj626 if you do not mind, I will "copy" something inspired by your example into the pgfplots manual as an example for how to provide polar coordinates into a cartesian axis using `data cs=polar` (your example is prettier than mine in the manual)

Answer (score 38):

The hardest part is to parametrize the curve. There are lots of ways to do this, one such way is

```
x(t) = (2+.5*cos(nt))cos(t)
y(t) = (2+.5*cos(nt))sin(t)
```

where `0\leq t\leq 2\pi` and `n\in \{3, 4, 5, ....\}`

If you vary the `.5` it will vary the sharpness of the curve.

Once you have this, you can plot the curve easily using `pgfplots` and its `\addplot` command

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis equal,axis lines=none]
 \addplot[samples=100,domain=0:2*pi,thick] ({(2+.5*cos(deg(5*x)))*cos(deg(x))},{(2+.5*cos(deg(5*x)))*sin(deg(x))});
 \addplot[samples=50,domain=0:2*pi,dashed] ({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Animation: vary n**

[image: vary n]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in{3,4,...,10}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis equal,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,
    ymin=-3,ymax=3,
    axis lines=none]
 \addplot[samples=400,domain=0:2*pi,thick] ({(2+.3*cos(deg(\n*x)))*cos(deg(x))},{(2+.3*cos(deg(\n*x)))*sin(deg(x))});
 \addplot[samples=40,domain=0:2*pi,dashed] ({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});
 \node at (axis cs:0,0){$n=\n$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

**Animation: vary 'sharpness' of the curve**

[image: animate1]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\foreach \r in{0.1,0.2,...,1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis equal,
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,
    ymin=-3,ymax=3,
    axis lines=none]
 \addplot[samples=300,domain=0:2*pi,thick] ({(2+\r*cos(deg(5*x)))*cos(deg(x))},{(2+\r*cos(deg(5*x)))*sin(deg(x))});
 \addplot[samples=40,domain=0:2*pi,dashed] ({2*cos(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x))});
 \node at (axis cs:0,0){$r=\r$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

See [How to convert pstricks animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73545/how-to-convert-pstricks-animation-to-gif-file) for full details of the rest of the animation creation process (just a couple of steps).

Comment: GarbageCollector has a rival, I see!

Answer (score 14):

Here is another TikZ solution...

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\r{1cm}
  \def\v{2.5mm}
  \foreach \n in {3,4,5,6}{
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\n*2*(\r+\v+1mm)]
      \draw[thick]  (0:{\r+\v})
      \foreach \a in {1,...,359}{ -- (\a:{\r+cos(\a*\n)*\v}) } -- cycle;
      \draw[dashed] circle (\r);
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're not too bothered about the exact equation, here's a method using the [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package (although you'd need the development version for it to work with `foreach`, it's nearly ready for upload to CTAN - just needs documentation - but for now it can be found at [TeX-SX Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files), download `hobby.dtx` and run `tex hobby.dtx`).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82773/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed]
    (0,0) circle[radius=3cm];
\def\n{8}
\def\amp{1}
\draw[use Hobby shortcut] ([closed]3-\amp,0) \foreach \k in {1,...,\n}
{ .. (\k*360/\n:{3+(Mod(\k,2) == 1 ? \amp : -\amp)})};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Two obvious parameters: `\n` is twice the number of "lumps" and `\amp` is the (half) amplitude.

I don't know how to do fancy animations, so here's a static image:

[image: bumpy circles with hobby]

Answer (score 7):

Just 4 fun with PSTricks. (and probably Bohr used PSTricks to illustrate his atomic model.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset
{
    unit=\psrunit,
    polarplot,
    algebraic=true,
    plotpoints=150,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2}
\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{2+.5*sin(3*x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animated version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset
{
    unit=\psrunit,
    polarplot,
    algebraic=true,
    plotpoints=1000,
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=2+1}{25}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2}
\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{2+.5*sin(\i*x)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

### Edit:

I am a bit lazy to redo my work above. Please try `cos` instead of `sin` if  you want to shift the curve `period/4` along the angular direction.

### The last edit:

The requested random magic by Doctor Kumar is given as follow. Please compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape bohring`.

```
% the filename of this code is bohring (not boring!)
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\def\filename{Bohr}

\begin{filecontents*}{\filename}
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset
{
    unit=\psrunit,
    polarplot,
    algebraic=true,
    plotpoints=1000,
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{25}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed](0,0){2}
\psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{2+.5*cos(\i*x)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{animate}

\immediate\write18{latex \filename}
\immediate\write18{dvips \filename}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf \filename.ps}

% begin cleaning
% The following codes are written with Windows' shell commands only for Windows user.
% If you use Linux, then ask other people to translate the codes to Linux's equivalent. 
% If you have no friend who can help you, just comment the code and manually remove the associated files.
\makeatletter
\@for\x:={tex,dvi,ps,log,aux}\do{\immediate\write18{cmd /c del \filename.\x}}
\makeatother
% end cleaning

\begin{document}
\animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,scale=1]{2}{\filename}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the code doesn't contain `convert` magic line ? `;-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar: Can you remove the `preview` environment sandwiching the `animategraphics` as `standalone` does it by default? I am limited by the system so I can have 5 edits a day.

Comment: Done. Is it OK?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thank you very much. It suits my intent.