# Updated chemfig gives errors for previously working code

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I've just installed TeX Live 2015 vanilla and I tried to compile some old sources just to be sure that everything worked. TeX Live works, but I have problems with some code that I've unashamedly stolen from a couple of sources on the net. I get a

```
! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `18.70836' by `0.0', but I cannot divide any number by `0.0' (in ' 18.70836pt/ int(18.70836pt/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength )')
```

for something related to the `wavy bond` part. *No wavy bonds in the document, no error*. This is the WE, as minimal as it could get (not much):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134259/custom-decoration-along-curved-paths
\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}{% tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25678/nicer-wavy-line-with-tikz/
    \state{initial}[
        width=+0pt,
        next state=sine,
        persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
            \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength / int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)}
            \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
        }] {}
    \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
    \state{final}{}
}
% From http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/
% and http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/26/exploring-chemfig-going-further/
\newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
\setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}
\newcommand*{\bondboldwidth}{0.22832 em} %'Bold Width'
\newcommand*{\bondhashlength}{0.25737 em} % 'Hash Spacing'

\tikzset{
  wavy bond/.style =
    {
      decorate,
      decoration =
        {
          complete sines,
          amplitude   = \bondboldwidth,
          post length = 0 pt,
          pre length  = 0 pt,
          % Use the atom spacing: saved 
          segment length = 
            \the\dimexpr\csname CF@atom@sep\endcsname/5\relax
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{A-[,,,,wavy bond]B}
\end{document}
```

Versions of the defendants:

```
chemfig.sty    2015/11/20 v1.2c Draw molecule with an easy syntax
   tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
    pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
```

Previously I was on TeX Live 2014 from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: I can confirm it works with vanilla TL 2014 and not 2015. (2014 updated to freeze, 2015 updated not that long ago.)

Comment: Probably useful to note that the code from the references TeX SE questions still compiles OK.

Comment: The problem is the setting of segment length. Without that, it compiles.

Comment: But it is not the changes to **chemfig** as the problem occurs if I drop the 2014 version into a 2015 compile. So, I guess this is a change to PGF/TikZ...

Comment: Use `segment length` without `\dimexpr`: `segment length = \csname CF@atom@sep\endcsname/5`

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't trace the cause for the change, but the problem is in your code and not in `chemfig`.

The macro `\CF@atom@sep` expands to `3em`, unless `\setatomsep` is issued. What happens is that, with previous versions of TikZ/PGF, your

```
segment length=\the\dimexpr\csname CF@atom@sep\endcsname/5\relax
```

was evaluated when the current font was the standard text font; with the current version, at that time the current font is `\nullfont`, so 3em is the same as zero.

Indeed, if I do

```
segment length=6pt
```

the example works.