# Confusing behavior of uput with non-zero dimensional object

Tags: pstricks

I really don't understand the behavior of `\uput` with non-zero dimensional object as illustrated below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{multido} 

\def\NonZeroDimenObject{%
    \pspicture(2,2)
        \psframe(2,1)
    \endpspicture}

\begin{document} 

\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,8)
    \pscircle(4,4){1.414}
    \rput(4,4){$\i^\circ$}
    \uput{1.414}[\i]{0}(4,4){\NonZeroDimenObject}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Which point on the frame should be used as a reference to understand how `\uput` works?

### Edit:

In other words, which points on the frame or inside the frame or outside the frame move with a circular trajectory?

Comment: Not my area, but +1 for a well "framed" question and extremely helpful graphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\NonZeroDimenObject` you created is based on a `pspicture` of size `(2,2)`. The frame inside of it only stretches from the origin `(0,0)` only as far out as `(2,1)`, leaving a vertical gap above it of size `1`. As such, the frame/rectangle is pushed downward when being `\uput` past 180 degrees. You should use the following definition:

```
\def\NonZeroDimenObject{%
    \pspicture(2,1)
        \psframe(2,1)
    \endpspicture}
```

[image]

<sub>For those interested in creating animated GIFs as output displays, see [How to convert pstricks animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73545/5764)</sub>

Comment: Oh my ghost. I did not realize that. :-)

Comment: @Bugbusters: While we'll be going on our daily lives, these frames will be circling and circling and circling and circling and...

Comment: Do you know which points on/inside/outside the frame move in a circular trajectory?

Comment: @bugbusters I don't think any of them do.