# arara: problem with animate.yaml

Tags: conversion, arara, gif

I wanted to automate conversion from pdf to animated gif with [`animate` rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116137/1952) provided by cmhughes in answer to [plotting the sequence x_n using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116128/1952).

I'm using arara+texworks+miktex on windows. I also have imagemagick installed and working from command line.

I've saved cmhughes code as `animate.yaml` in my `\rules` folder. I add

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: animate
```

to my tex file (as example, [this pgfplots code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116137/1952)) and compile it with `arara`. The result is a correct pdf file but when starts `animate` it shows a message with

```
Running animate ...

Parámetro no válido: 10
FAILURE
```

`Parámetro no válido` means `non valid parameter` and I don't know which program (arara, convert) shows it.

I'm using arara from TeXworks with options `--log` and `--verbose`. After compiling a tex file, `arara.log` contains:

```
05 Jun 2013 15:52:58.687 INFO  Arara - Welcome to arara!
05 Jun 2013 15:52:58.687 INFO  Arara - Processing file '117309.tex', please wait.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:58.703 INFO  DirectiveExtractor - Reading directives from 117309.tex.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:58.703 TRACE DirectiveExtractor - Directive found in line 1 with animate: {density: 200, delay: 10}.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:58.812 INFO  DirectiveParser - Parsing directives.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:58.812 INFO  TaskDeployer - Deploying tasks into commands.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:58.812 TRACE TaskDeployer - Task 'animate' found in 'D:\Archivos de programa\arara\rules'.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:59.125 INFO  CommandTrigger - Ready to run commands.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:59.125 INFO  CommandTrigger - Running 'animate'.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:59.125 TRACE CommandTrigger - Command: convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 200 "117309.pdf" "117309.gif"
05 Jun 2013 15:52:59.265 TRACE CommandTrigger - Output logging:
05 Jun 2013 15:52:59.265 TRACE CommandTrigger - Par metro no v lido: 10

05 Jun 2013 15:52:59.265 WARN  CommandTrigger - 'animate' returned an error status.
05 Jun 2013 15:52:59.265 INFO  Arara - Done.
```

(empty line is original, not my mistake editing it)

In any case, running command

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 300 myfile.pdf myfile.gif
```

from command window works and creates a gif file. This command is what it's trying to do `arara: animate`.

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add the flags `-v -l` to the compilation of `arara`. Then you have a verbosed arara log file.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Nothing changes. I've added `arara.log` results.

Comment: Please add the option `-debug All` to convert. Then you get an output of the log of `convert`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel If I add `-debug All` to convert on command line I can see a lot of information but conversion still works. If I the option to `yaml` file: `- <arara> convert -debug All -delay @{delay} -loop @{loop} -density @{density} "@{getBasename(file)}.pdf" "@{getBasename(file)}.gif" > test.log 2>&1`. Still nothing changes. The error is the same, process stops in same place and nothing is written in `test.log`.

Comment: I had a similar issue as I used the rule `indent` out of my editor. From the terminal everything works fine. I suppose you are compiling the document from the terminal with arara too.

Comment: @Ignasi: I suspect the "wrong" `convert` is being called (Windows has also a tool named `convert`, so there's a name clash). I have no Windows machine near me right now, so I cannot say for sure which PATH `arara` is assuming (either user or system, I suspect system). As a workaround, replace `- <arara> convert` in Chris' `animate` rule by the full path to ImageMagick's `convert`, say, `- <arara> "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\bin\convert.exe"` (I don't know the exact path) and try running `arara` again. Please tell me if this works, otherwise we have to come up with another solution. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: You were right. With the full path, it worked. What I don't understand is why `arara` starts `windows convert` and `command line` starts `ImageMagick convert`. In any case, problem solved. If you think this question is `not too localized` and want to write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Ignasi: I have a suspicion that the ImageMagick's path is set in your user variables settings, and `arara` relies solely on the system path. I'll investigate about it (I just need a Windows machine first), don't worry. `:)` I'll write an answer later on too. `:)`

Comment: how about using the `cmd c/`, as in `- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c convert", "convert" ) } -delay @{delay} -loop @{loop} -density @{density} "@{ getBasename(file) }.pdf" "@{ getBasename(file) }.gif"`

Comment: @cmhughes: Your solution also works. If I've well understood this solution is equivalent to running `convert` from a command terminal and as I've ImageMagick's path in my user settings, ImageMagick's convert is the one which runs. Nice!

Comment: @Ignasi yes indeed- I'll test it myself later today and write an answer, I'll chat with Paulo later too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## arara version 4.0 answer

`arara` version 4.0 ships with `animate.yaml`, and Windows users might use the following, for example:

```
% arara: animate: {program: magick.exe}
```

### old answer, out of date

> *The answer below is out of date*

I apologize for not making my rule robust enough :)

As noted in the comments, the problem with my original answer is that Windows might not get the path correct. You can fix it by using

```yaml
- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c convert", "convert" ) } -delay @{delay} -loop @{loop} -density @{density} "@{ getBasename(file) }.pdf" "@{ getBasename(file) }.gif"
```

Here's a complete, cross-platform, version

```yaml
!config
# Make animated .gif file from .pdf
# author: Chris Hughes
# last edited by: cmh, June 6th 2013
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage: 
#
# % arara: animate
# % arara: animate: {density: 200}
# % arara: animate: {density: 200, delay: 20}
#
# This rule is really just a shortcut for commands like the following
#
#  convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 300 myfile.pdf myfile.gif
#
# which will output myfile.gif
#
identifier: animate
name: animate
commands: 
- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c convert", "convert" ) } -delay @{delay} -loop @{loop} -density @{density} "@{ getBasename(file) }.pdf" "@{ getBasename(file) }.gif"
arguments:
- identifier: delay
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.delay}
  default: 10
- identifier: loop
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.loop}
  default: 0
- identifier: density
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.density}
  default: 300
```

Comment: Oh a Windows user ;-)

Comment: Thank you for `animate.yaml`. Now it will be easier (at least for me) to submit animated gif's to TeX.SX. :-)

Comment: @Ignasi no problem, glad it helped :) `isWindows` is pretty darned useful :)

Comment: I'm using your `animate.yaml` with `arara` on Windows 10 and all works well except for the `loop` parameter: even if I set it to `1`, I always get an infinite loop. It is not a problem of your rule because also the command `convert -delay 10 -loop 1 -density 300 myfile.pdf myfile.gif` has the same problem. Could you help me? I know this is not TEX.SE related, where should I ask it?

Comment: @CarLaTeX perhaps Stack overflow, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick-convert (note the tags)....?

Comment: They've already answered me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40442936/6689867. The problem was not the command but the program I used to open the `.gif` file! You always find a rapid solution on the StackExchange communities, you all are great!