# How to design shapes in beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to prepare a presentation in `beamer`. I would like to include some shapes in some of the slides. I would like to ask what is the best way to do so. Is it better to draw the shapes using another software and then add them in the tex file, or is there any package that allows me to do so in the tex file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this- since your question was a little vague, I can't be sure if this is the kind of thing you want:

[image: animation]

It uses the very powerful and user-friendly [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) package. There are lots of other things and shapes that you can do with this package, this is just an example.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: animate: {delay: 60}
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}

    \makebox[\textwidth]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={cloud,draw,double,very thick,align=center}]
            \node[fill=red!20, draw=red,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1.5cm,cloud puffs=10, aspect=2.0] (installation){1. Installation\\ \& easy document};
            \visible<2->{\node[cloud,below right=of installation,draw=blue,fill=blue!20, cloud puffs=13, aspect=1.3](buildingblocks)    {2. Building\\ blocks};}
            \visible<3->{\node[left=0.75cm of buildingblocks, draw=yellow,fill=yellow!20, minimum height=1.5cm, cloud puffs=17, aspect=2](tables){3. Tables\\\& floats};}
            \visible<4->{\node[left=0.75cm of tables, draw=green,fill=green!20, cloud puffs=13, aspect=3](figures){4. Home-made \\ figures};}
            \visible<5->{\node[left=.3cm of installation, draw=orange,fill=orange!30, cloud puffs=12, aspect=2.3]{5. Big documents\\\& presentations};}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Did you already have this code or you typed it now? +1.

Comment: @Sigur I must confess, I had the code already from a conference presentation earlier this year :)

Comment: +1. `arara: animate: {delay: 60}`? Wow. Chris, can you please email the arara rule to me for that?.

Comment: @HarishKumar thanks! here's a link to the rule: [arara: problem with animate.yaml](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117727) will be in touch :)