# How can I use arara to get a graphics file?

Tags: programming, png, output, ghostscript, arara

In a standard TeX Live distribution [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) is, to my knowledge, present; it is hidden, but it is there.

**Edit: Yes, it is under**

```
\Texlive\2013\tlpkg\tlgs
```

So to my question:

How can I use [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara), to activate the *internal* Ghostscript to get a graphics file as an output? For example `mydocument.png`  (in addition to `mydocument.pdf`).

Note, that I do not ask, how can I convert a PDF to a PNG (we know there are 1000s of possibilities), I am interested to use only internal TeX Live tools (that means NO extra software) and let `arara` do the job.

Comment: Knowing how you would use `ghostscript` to make the PNG files from the PDF is better. Is it a single page PDF? Do you want to crop it to a minimal bounding box? However, as far as I know, `ghostscript` is not included in TeX Live.

Comment: Oh, that is a good question. For example: I create a TikZ-picture in the standalone-class, so I am interessted to have that as a png. I also thought about the preview-package, to get special parts of my document as a preview; and this I would like to have as a png too ;)

Comment: Which platform are you on? MacTeX includes some extras although it did not used to provide `ghostscript` as far as I know. It did used to provide a stripped down `convert` independent of ImageMagick. No idea if I am misremembering or if, if not, it still does, though...

Comment: Ghostscript can be found under    \Texlive\2013\tlpkg\tlgs   in windows ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `standalone`, you may create a specific `arara` rule.

Inspired by [the `animate` rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117972/101651) provided by cmhughes, I have created a `convertgs.yaml` rule and put in `...\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\arara\rules` (the path varies according to which operating system and TeX distribution you are using, I have MiKTeX):

Note that I have used `mgs` because `mgs.exe` is the Ghostscript executable which came with the MikTeX 2.9 installation, I have discovered it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214646/101651), maybe you have to change it with your executable name.

Moreover, I have tested this rule only with Windows 10, even if I think this works also with other operating systems.

```
!config
# Convert .pdf to any format file allowed by Ghostscript (the default is png)
# author: CarLaTeX
# last edited by: CarLaTeX, November 16th 2016
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage: 
# - these both create a .png file:
# % arara: convertgs
# % arara: convertgs: {format: png}
#
# - this creates a .ps file:
# % arara: convertgs: {device: ps2write, format: ps}
#
# This rule is really just a shortcut for commands like the following:
#
#  mgs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile=myfile.png myfile.pdf
#
# which will output myfile.png
#
# Attention: 1. I have used `mgs` because `mgs.exe` is then Ghostscript executable which came with the MikTeX 2.9
#                installation, maybe you have to change it with your executable name.
#            2. I have tested this rule only with Windows 10.
#
identifier: convertgs
name: convertgs
commands: 
- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c mgs", "mgs" ) } -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=@{device} -r@{density} -sOutputFile="@{ getBasename(file) }.@{format}" "@{ getBasename(file) }.pdf"
arguments:
- identifier: device
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.device}
  default: png16m
- identifier: density
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.density}
  default: 600
- identifier: format
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.format}
  default: png
```

(Take also into account that I'm not an expert, maybe this could be done better).

Of course, you have to do this once for all, then it is sufficient to put:

```
% arara: pdflatex               (or any other command you are using to compile)
% arara: ...                    (possible other commands)
% arara: convertgs
```

at the beginning of your document and compile it with `arara`.

For example, if you have this `myfile.tex`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: convertgs
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Quack!
\end{document}
```

and you run `arara myfile.tex`, you will get a `myfile.pdf` and a `myfile.png`.

For an analogous solution with `convert` command of ImageMagick see [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339227/101651).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple way to get what you need with `standalone`:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass[
  convert,
  outext=.png,
  tikz,
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [red] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt]
(1,1) circle [radius=2pt] (2,1) circle [radius=2pt] (2,0) circle [radius=2pt];
  \draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,1) .. (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will use `convert` and needs ImageMagick, which can be easily installed. Conversion using `ghostscript` is possible, but you need tweaking the parameters. With the default ones, the conversion with `convert` is good, with `ghostscript` (that you get by `convert=ghostscript`) is quite bad.

The conversion with `ghostscript` is obtained with

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass[
  convert=ghostscript,
  tikz,
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [red] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt]
(1,1) circle [radius=2pt] (2,1) circle [radius=2pt] (2,0) circle [radius=2pt];
  \draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,1) .. (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Examining the `.log` file I see

```
runsystem(gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile=gsconv-%d.png gsconv.pdf)...executed.
```

which shows that `ghostscript` is called. You may need to do some adjustment to the internal parameters, in particular for helping `standalone` in finding the ghostscript executable. I can't be more precise, because I don't have Windows (and never will).

Comment: Thank you! So we have a solution with the extra-software ImageMagick.   But I ask me, if there is a elementary solution with the ghostscript, wich you can found under \Texlive\2013\tlpkg\tlgs (in Windows)?