# What format to compile animations created with tikz to (non pdf)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, animations

I was looking at the post over at [Nice scientific pictures show off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off). And people have created some abselutly awesome pictures and animations.

That got me wondering, what is the best format to compile an animation to? 
If you have a pdf viewer that support animations they can easily be shown there, but many pdf viewers cannot do this.

I looked around for an answer, but most answers are about how to put the animation within a pdf document. I also couldn't find any answers to what might be a good format, or wether you can compile to formats such as gif.

Thus what is the best format for tikz animations and how do you do this?

Comment: As long as FlashPlayer plugin is maintained for web browsers, I would convert multipage PDF animations to SWF, as SWF keeps the vector graphics nature. An open-source tool exists for  this purpose: `pdf2swf` from http://www.swftools.org

Comment: these are `.gif` files; you'll find the instructions at various points on the site, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116128/plotting-the-sequence-x-n-using-tikz

Comment: Gif is of inferior quality than SWF because it is compressed bitmap which does not scale well.

Comment: thanks @AlexG, guess I was just bad at googeling. However flash is currently being closed down. What will be the best format after this happens? (a vector animation, but not in pdf format?)

Comment: As animated SVG is also dead, HTML5 will win the race. However, I don't know of an open-source or free conversion tool. HTML5 animation is JavaScript driven drawing on the `<canvas>` element.

Comment: Really good idea, googeling will fastly find the open source project: https://github.com/pyramation/LaTeX2HTML5