# How to simplify my code with looping macros?

Tags: pstricks, multido

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}

 \pswedge(0,0){2}{0}{15}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{15}{30}
  \pswedge(0,0){2}{30}{45}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{45}{60}

 \pswedge(0,0){2}{60}{75}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{75}{90}
  \pswedge(0,0){2}{90}{105}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{105}{120}

  \pswedge(0,0){2}{120}{135}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{135}{150}
  \pswedge(0,0){2}{150}{165}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{165}{180}

  \pswedge(0,0){2}{180}{195}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{195}{210}
  \pswedge(0,0){2}{210}{225}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{225}{240}

 \pswedge(0,0){2}{240}{255}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{255}{270}
  \pswedge(0,0){2}{270}{285}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{285}{300}

 \pswedge(0,0){2}{300}{315}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{315}{330}
  \pswedge(0,0){2}{330}{345}
 \pswedge*(0,0){2}{345}{360}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\foreach` from `pgffor` package is also available by default in PSTricks. As a result, you don't need to use `\multido`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\foreach \i [evaluate = \i as \j using \i+15] in {0,30,..., 330}{\pswedge*{2}{\i}{\j}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is exactly the same as other answers.

Comment: there are so many solutions ! thank  you very much.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}

\def\obj#1{%
    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
        \multido{\i=#1+30}{12}{\rput{\i}(0,0){\pswedge*(0,0){2}{0}{15}}}
    \end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\obj{0}\obj{15}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Starred `\pswedge` does not need `linestyle=none,linewidth=0` to remove the outline because it has been done automatically.

Comment: thanks a lot, very good, and I wonder how you created the gif picture?

Comment: how to upvote your answer, i have ticked your answer as useful answer

Comment: @dozer: For free, see [How to convert `pstricks` animation to GIF file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73545/5764)

Comment: more simple, could you add any notes about the syntax like obj#1, \obj{0}\obj{15}, thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \multido{\i=0+15}{24}{%
    \def\dowedge{\pswedge}%
    \ifodd\i\def\dowedge{\pswedge*}\fi
    \dowedge(0,0){2}{\i}{\number\numexpr\i+15}%
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Potentially one could also draw a filled, black circle and insert 12 white wedges.

---

As a secondary request, you can set the `linestyle` to `none`, which removes the outer circle as well as the "inner dot". Effectively, there is then no need for printing the white wedges then, making to code a little lighter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
    \pswedge*(0,0){2}{\i}{\number\numexpr\i+15}%
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very good idea, better than my primal idea

Answer (score 2):

Define first a circle with 24 degrees. Makes things easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\degrees[24]
\multido{\i=0+2}{12}{\pswedge*{2}{\i}{!\i\space 1 add}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a very good idea