# How to mark a segment?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,newcent}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,0,-90}](1,2){M_1}(2,1){M_2}(1,0){M_3}
\pstSegmentMark{M_1}{M_2} %%%%\pstSegmentMark
\pstSegmentMark{M_2}{M_3}
\pstSegmentMark{M_3}{M_1}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={90,0,-90}](1,2){M_1}(2,1){M_2}(1,0){M_3}
\pstMarkSegment{M_1}{M_2}  %%%%\pstMarkSegment
\pstMarkSegment{M_2}{M_3}
\pstMarkSegment{M_3}{M_1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of compiling :

[image]

**In pst-eucl documentation (v.1.59), the general syntax is :**

[image]

**But in the latter example, the syntax is :**

[image]

***The default value of is \MarkHashh, not \pstslashh.***

Question:

According to the above result, **\pstMarkSegment is failed**,  Should I choose one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the following.

[image]

## Edit

Responding to your comment below.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){O}(4,4){A}
    \uput[180](A){Angle = $\i^\circ$}
    \pstSegmentMark[SegmentSymbol=MarkHashhh,MarkAngle=\i]{O}{A}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give me for an example about the parameter SegmentSymbol and the parameter MarkAngle. I don't know.

Comment: @chishimotoji: Navigate to [this tutorial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73547/87876).

Answer (score 3):

It is a typo in the documentation. The code beside the examples is always correct. Hence it should be `\pstSegmentMark`. See also http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/doc/generic/pst-eucl/

For something like `SegmentSymbol=...` use the name without the preceeding backslash. However, there also exists the macros with the same name, eg `\MarkHash` which can be used for other purposes.

Comment: The default value is \MarkHashh, not \pstslashh. Can you explain to me about it?

Comment: Also a typo. However, the current version is 1.60, you should first update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Are you sure??? No change in v1.6

Comment: @chishimotoji: However, I'll upload a 1.60a, which has the correct naming.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: I think it is better to replace the last 2 segments (in the given example of the documentation) with `\pstSegmentMark[MarkAngle=45,SegmentSymbol=MarkHash]{D}{E}
\pstSegmentMark[MarkAngle=30,SegmentSymbol=MarkCross]{E}{A}` to illustrate how to use `SegmentSymbol` and `MarkAngle`.