# How can I change graphics with timeout in a beamer?

Tags: graphics, include

Is there a way to include several graphics on the same place on the frame, but at different times?

Personally, I would like to roll 3-4 pictures repeatedly changing on every, say, 10 seconds. All of them staying on the same place on the frame.

I know how to do this with the command \only, but that would require a user to change to "next frame" in order to display next picture.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the beamer user guide (http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), chapter 14: Animations, Sounds, and Slide Transitions.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
\transduration<(overlay specification)>{(number of seconds)}
```

In full screen mode, show the slide for `(number of seconds)`. If zero is specified, the slide is shown as short as possible. This can be used to create interesting pseudo-animations.
Example: `\transduration<2>{1}`

Comment: Yes, I've heard of \transduration, but I don't know how to go back to first picture again after the last one. Do you know how to do it? Also, is it possible to specify \includegraphics<1><3><5> to show picture on several (but only these) "frames"? That would solve the problem for 2-3 circles, but still not enough...

Comment: If you go to the first picture again, you'd get an infinite loop, how are you going to step out?

As to the second question, it's like this: \includegraphics<1,3,5>

Comment: Well, stepping out is with hitting the space, but while I am on the frame I want it to keep rolling pictures in the loop. Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you thought of using a gif? Check one of these: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file/10381#10381,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file/7603#7603