# Animation using a sequence of images in a single pdf file

Tags: beamer, pdftex, animations

I have a sequence of images in one pdf file. The first page in the pdf corresponds to the first step in the animation, the second page corresponds to the second step in the animation and in general, the `n th` page corresponds to the `n th` step in the animation. I want to run this animation from he pdf file in a single beamer frame and run the animation with a gap of `1 second` between each page of the pdf. How do I go about doing this? I use `pdflatex`. Let us say the pdf file has 100 pages and each page contains the image sequentially for the animation and the name of the pdf file is `animation.pdf`.

Comment: fyi, this might be of use also http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/PDFmovie.html  `Including animations in PDF using LaTeX` (the page is a little outdated, but thought it might be useful as it talks about using latex to make animations in pdf)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the *animate* package to do this:

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{1}{animation}{}{}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The syntax is the following:

`\animategraphics[<options>]{<frames per second>}{<name without extension>}{<first frame>}{<last frame>}`

If you don't specify `<first frame>` or `<last frame>`, the first respectively last page are used. In the given example the `<options>` make the animation looping continuosely. Other things, as control buttons (start, stop etc.) are possible, [please refer to the manual](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) for more options.

Comment: When I use the following command, `\animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{1}{./animation.pdf}{1}{61}`, I get the following errors:






`! Package animate Error: Neither of the files
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.pdf',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.mps',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.png',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.jpg',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.jpeg',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.jbig2',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.jb2',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.jp2',
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.j2k' or
(animate) `./animation.pdf1.jpx',
(animate) could be found.
(animate) Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?.`

Comment: You have to leave out the extension, so `\animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{1}{./animation}{1}{61}`

Comment: Thanks. This is a very cool package. I have searching for such a nice package for couple of years. Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome. I also only learned of this package through this site :D

Comment: One last question. Is there a way to add caption to the video? I looked at the manual [here](http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf), but was not able to find any.

Comment: Probably but the whole thing in a figure environment? Like `\begin{figure} <animation> \caption{my caption} \end{figure}`.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I have done now. Thanks, this is probably the most useful package, I have been looking for a long time. Thanks again.

Comment: @user17762: Thanks for praising and using `animate`.

Comment: Sorry to buzz you again. @AlexG If I run it under Ubuntu, I get the following message `! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3} \fi 
l.137 ... \csname newdimen\endcsname \scratchdimen
`, `! No room for a new \dimen . \ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3} \fi 
l.1253 \newdimen\MPscratchDim % will be assigned global` and `! No room for a new \dimen . \ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3} \fi 
l.304 \newdimen\@anim@tmpdima %length registers for occasional use`, though the file compile and the movie plays in the pdf. How to fix this?

Comment: @AlexG Ok. I figured out a way to fix this by using `\usepackage{etex}`. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to increase the speed of animation without skipping any of the frames?

Answer (score 6):

**Notice of obsolescense:**
The embedded playback of Flash content is no longer possible due to EOL of Flash and FlashPlayer.

---

Alternatively, the `media9` package can be used, `movie15` is outdated, and playback, of GIF files in particular, is very unreliable as it depends on third-party plug-ins used by AdobeReader.

For use with `media9`, the PDF needs to be converted to SWF, using [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org/). This conversion keeps the vector-graphical nature of the original file:

```
pdf2swf  --set framerate=1 --output animation.swf animation.pdf
```

The frame rate is adjusted to 1 FPS, as requested.

Inclusion is done as:

```
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
...

\includemedia{\includegraphics[page=1]{animation}}{animation.swf}
```

The first page of the original `animation.pdf` is used as the poster image.

Comment: Hmm, but you also can't play Flash on all machines either. A lot of Linux people I know don't have installed any programm for playing `.swf` files and curse anyone using them ;)

Comment: @Tom: Yes that is certain. It was more thought as a reply to Peters answer, which probably has the lowest mileage of all given here.

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Animated .gif:

You can produce an animated `.gif` file via:

```
pdfcrop animation.pdf
```

and then use `convert` from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to obtain a `.gif` file. So something like:

```
 convert -verbose -delay 100 -loop 0 -density 400 animation-crop.pdf animation.gif
```

---

### 2. Include .gif:

As per [How to add a gif file to my LaTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file)
the `.gif` file can be included by including the `movie15` package in the preamble:

```
\includemovie{1cm}{1cm}{animation.gif}
```

Comment: I tried that before but it gives the following error:

`! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.170 \newdimen\@MXV@braiselen`

Comment: `movie15` is horribly outdated, @Peter, and playback is extremely unreliable. It is much better to use either `animate` or `media9`. For the latter, one has to convert the PDF to SWF (the vector-graphical nature is kept), using [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org/).