# Animation in beamer, not a png per slide

Tags: beamer, animations

I see there are several questions about inserting animations into tex beamers. I have tried several of the suggested methods, but always get the same output: a png per slide instead of one slide with an animation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Embedded Animation}
    \transduration<0-8>{0}
    \multiinclude[<+->][format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth}] {pres_plots/images/flumap}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \Value in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    \node<\Value> (pres_plots/images/flumap-\Value){\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pres_plots/images/flumap-\Value}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{center}
    \includegraphics<1>[width=.5\linewidth]{pres_plots/images/flumap-0}
    \includegraphics<2>[width=.5\linewidth]{pres_plots/images/flumap-1}
    \includegraphics<3>[width=.5\linewidth]{pres_plots/images/flumap-2}
 \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first solution is an animation if you open it in a suitable pdf viewer (e.g. adobe reader) in presentation view. It will automatically play the 8 slides within the frame.

Comment: If you really want to have only a single slide, try the animate package, but it requires a pdf viewer capable of JavaScript

Comment: @samcarter, thanks! Any idea why the others don't work?

Comment: The third example can easily be animated using `\transduration<0-3>{0}`. The second one probably as well, but I did not test this one.

Comment: @samcarter, ah, transduration is needed as well! And the number in the {} sets the speed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first example you show is a perfectly fine animation. To view it open it in a suitable pdf viewer (e.g. adobe reader) in presentation view. It will automatically play the 8 slides within the frame. The key element to this example is

```
\transduration<0-8>{0}
```

which means, that the first 8 slides in this frame will be automatically played for a duration of 0 seconds -- which translates into a finite amount of time the pdf viewer needs to change the slides.

Using this line, you can animate your other two examples in the same way.

---

If you don't like this multiples slides per frame concept, there is also the `animate` package which uses JavaScript (check if your pdfviewer has this) to show the animations within a single slide.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117556/36296 for a short example.

---

Please consider: if the pdf viewer does not support the method you choose (for example if you present from a foreign computer) you can still manually step through the slides in the first case, but with the javascript solution you just won't see anything.