# Animation in one slide

Tags: beamer, overlays, animations

I write a presentation with several slide contain `\enumerate{}`. If an `\enumerate{}` contains 5 `\item`, then each item expanding into five pages. Can I play animation of Beamer in one slide only?

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}  
\useinnertheme{default}  
\usepackage{libertine}  
\usepackage{animate}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{textpos}  
\usetheme{Warsaw}  
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=lightgray!40}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{\textbf{Latar Belakang}}  
\textbf{Latar Belakang}  
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]  
    \item Text line 1  
    \item Text line 2  
    \item Text line 3  
    \item Text line 4  
    \item Text line 5    
\end{enumerate}  
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, but if you are using a suitable pdf viewer you can make the 5 slides play automatically by setting the `transduration`.

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.

Comment: Instead of using `\textbf` in the frametitle, rather do `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}`

Comment: related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386867/animation-in-beamer-not-a-png-per-slide?rq=1

Comment: Thank you samcarter. But I don't need my \items play automatically. Two other points are very useful.

Comment: Then the answer is simply no, beamer overlays work by splitting a frame into separate slides.

Comment: Why do you want the animation to be in one slide? If you want to distribute copies of your slides and you don't want so many pages, then you can use `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`, which will create one page per frame (with all elements visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not using standard beamer overlays. Splitting a frame into multiple slides is how overlays work.

Using the `animate` package you could create an JavaScript based solution, which adds the text on the same slide, however you would need to change the syntax of your enumeration and use a pdf viewer capable of JavaScript.