# Error! animate package can't find the requested pdf file

Tags: animate

I'm just trying add some animation into my thesis, but pdf-backend still compliants to me, that requested file can't be found.

Also I would like to know how to proceed, if the image is not stored in the same directory. For attached MNWE, file is stored in same directory as compiled test.tex file.

If I am right, the syntax should be like (The number of frames need not be specified):

```
\animategraphics[<options>]{<frames per second>}{<name without extension>}{<first frame>}{<last frame>}
```

Compiled by:

- `lualatex --enable-write18 --shell-escape test.tex`  works NOK
- `pdflatex --enable-write18 --shell-escape test.tex`  works OK

MNWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}


\begin{document}
  text

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
   \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{2}{animation}{}{}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For sake of completens, I also try the answer in the similar post [Animation using a sequence of images in a single pdf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117543/animation-using-a-sequence-of-images-in-a-single-pdf-file), but the behavior is the same.

Code for generating PDF with 20 pages used for animation:

```
    % This animation helps explain the geometric interpretation of the 
    % definite integral.
    % http://texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-definite-integral/

    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz, pgf}
    \usepackage{multido}


    \begin{document}
    %
    \multido{\n=1+1}{20}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
        \draw[red,thick,<->] (-1,1) parabola bend (0,0) (2.1,4.41)
            node[below right] {\(y=x^2\)};
        \draw[loosely dotted] (-1,0) grid (4,4);
        \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.25,0) node[right] {\(x\)};
        \draw[->] (0,-0.25) -- (0,4.25) node[above] {\(y\)};
        \foreach \x/\xtext in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\(\xtext\)};
        \foreach \y/\ytext in {1/1, 2/2, 3/3, 4/4}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\(\ytext\)};
    %
        \def\mc{\n*\n}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\result{int(\n*\n*\n)}
        \shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray!50]
            (0,0) parabola (0.1*\n,0.01*\mc) |- (0,0);
        \node[draw, fill=white] at (3cm,2cm) 
        {\(\int\limits_0^{\frac{\n}{10}}\!\!x^2\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\result}{3000}\)};
        \draw[fill=black,color=black] (0.1*\n,0.01*\mc) circle (1.2pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The command looks correct. Does a simple `\includegraphics{animation}` find the file? (Its name should be `animation.pdf`, obviously a multipage PDF.)

Comment: You may use `\graphicspath{...}` to extend the list of paths to be searched for graphics files.

Comment: Also, case matters: `aniMation.PDF` might not be found.

Comment: @AlexG doesn't work for me either with lualatex (pdflatex is fine).

Comment: @Ulrike `lualatex` fails for some reason, that's new: due to recent changes of grf*-related pkgs or the renewed l2e format, perhaps? On the other hand, no problem with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`...

Comment: @AlexG You need to unquote the file name when using \pdfximage. I can give you code in the chat.

Comment: @Ulrike So, `\pdfximage` (pdfTeX) and `\saveimageresource` (LuaTeX) have different syntax? (I do `\let\pdfximage\saveimageresource` in pdfbase, as suggested in the LuaTeX manual.) AND I don't use quotes ...

Comment: @AlexG: You are author of the package Animate, or it is coincidence with Alexander Grahn :-). Sorry for off-topic.

Comment: @JardaFait No coincidence ;-)

Comment: @AlexG. I try to use the package 'luatex85' because it provides emulation of pdfTEX primitives for LuaTEX, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that, even with the pdflatex-compiled version, the animation does not work if the final pdf is opened in Mac Preview. (It does, however, work as expected if opened on a Mac using Adobe Acrobat Reader.)

Comment: @murray Preview has never worked. `animate`-type PDF-animations run in AR, Foxit, PDFXChange. Apart from this, you can produce animated SVG which run everywhere, where Chromium-based browsers exist. Firefox too, but with bad performance.

Comment: @AlexG: Can SVG graphics be created from LaTeX/TikZ and then be embedded in a PDF document that would run "anywhere"?

Comment: @murray No, SVG cannot be embedded into PDF without being converted itself to PDF before. Yet, SVG may be used as output format for complete documents instead of PDF, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235180 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luatex and pdftex handle quoted file names differently. A work-around (until animate is corrected) could be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\makeatletter
\def\@anim@getpagecount#1#2#3{%
    \edef\@anim@tempfilename{\noexpand\unquote@name{#1.#2}}%
    \pdfximage page 1 {\@anim@tempfilename}\xdef#3{\the\pdflastximagepages}%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  text

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
   \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{2}{example-image-duck}{}{}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for investigating this and providing a fix!

Comment: In the meantime, the fix should have been propagated to all mirrors of CTAN, TeXLive and MiKTeX. Thanks again.