# How can I create a blurred image effect in LaTeX using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, overlays

I am preparing a LaTeX `beamer` presentation. I want to have few frames with the blur effect on images to focus on different aspects at a time, just as in the image below.

[image]

I tried this by creating a semi-transparent (or low opacity) overlay that covers the entire image region and then keeping the image to focus on top of this (with full opacity).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\node[align=center, opacity=.1, text opacity=1] at (-2.8,1.5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{img/test.png}\\ Text 1};
\node[align=center, opacity=.1, text opacity=1] at (0,2.5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{img/test.png}\\ Text 2};
\node[align=center, opacity=.1, text opacity=1] at (2.8,1.5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{img/test.png}\\ Text 3};
\node[align=center, opacity=.1, text opacity=1] at (-2.8,-1.5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{img/test.png}\\ Text 4};
\node[align=center, opacity=.1, text opacity=1] at (0,-2.5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{img/test.png}\\ Text 5};
\node[align=center, opacity=.1, text opacity=1] at (2.8,-1.5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{img/test.png}\\ Text 6};
%Opac layer
\node[rectangle,fill=black, opacity=0.1, text opacity=1,minimum width=6cm, minimum height=6cm] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this does not create the desired blurred effect. Please suggest how I can achieve this using TikZ.

(Image taken from [here](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/dwu4/talks/VisaResearch1216.pdf).)

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295100/4778 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108817/4778

Comment: Or this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523284 . In any case, you will need an external programme to produce a blurred version of the graphic.

Comment: @Alenanno I did have a look at these. I was trying to avoid the `sagetex`-based approach. I was wondering whether there is some other way of doing it.
@AlexG I can try this, however, I have multiple images for which I have to do it. Let me see if I can find a better way. Thank you both for your suggestions.