# TeXstudio \includegraphics file not found

Tags: graphics

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Inside `\begin{document}` I have:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{supremum}
\end{figure}
```

`supremum.gif` is a gif file inside the same file as this `.tex` file. I have looked into other solutions but none have worked for me so far.

Comment: pdflatex does not support .gif

Comment: Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file

Answer (score 1):

I convert it to `.png` solved the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/131322)

Comment: @Zarko Since I solved it, how could I close the question?

Comment: you can left as it is (regardless to my opinion, that your answer is rather comment to your question). you also can accept your answer. question is closed as duplicate, so no more answers are possible.