# ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in ../images/vi.gif (no BoundingBox)

Tags: pandoc, gif

I have downloaded https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html file using `wget -p -k https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html` then run `pandoc --latex-engine=xelatex -o vi.pdf vi.html` this produce -

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in ../images/vi.gif (no Boundin
gBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.884 ...html}{\includegraphics{../images/vi.gif}}
```

And when I use `pdflatex`(default latex-engine in pandoc) by using `pandoc -o vi.pdf vi.html` this produce -

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .gif.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.884 ...html}{\includegraphics{../images/vi.gif}}
```

I also use `wkhtmltopdf https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html` to make pdf from weblink. But, in `wkhtmltopdf` solution I have no control over the background color. I want to make a black and white pdf.

Comment: Simple answer: gif is not supported by latex. Just convert your file to png or jpg or something that is supported.

Comment: @TeXnician I know too. But, I want to make the conversion automated.

Comment: You can use [Herbert's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7608/29873) and run pandoc with `--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape`

Comment: @DG' How can I use Herbert's code since I am not writing the code manually, I just call the pandoc with the html file.

Comment: Put the code in a FILE and call pandoc with the option `--include-in-header=FILE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take [Herbert's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file/7608#7608) and put it in a file:

```
% file: gif2png.tex
% Herbert's code:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/how-to-add-a-gif-file-to-my-latex-file/7608#7608

\usepackage{epstopdf}

\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{convert gif:#1 png:\OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}
```

Now you can call pandoc with the options: `--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape --include-in-header=gif2png.tex`

**Example:**

Take this simple html file:

```
<!-- file: test.html -->
<p>Here is a gif:</p>
<img src="test.gif" title="A dummy picture" alt="The gif" />
```

And a gif called `test.gif`:

[image]

And run pandoc:

```
pandoc test.html --pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape --include-in-header=gif2png.tex -o test.pdf
```

You will get this pdf as a result:

[image]

---

**Caveat:**

`epstopdf` supports only `pdflatex` and `lualatex` as pdf-engine

Comment: `pandoc: unrecognized option `--pdf-engine-opt=-shell-escape'`

Comment: You are probably using an old version of pandoc. You can either [install a more recent version](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) or use the old option: `--latex-engine-opt=--shell-escape`. Cf. https://github.com/shd101wyy/markdown-preview-enhanced/issues/665

Comment: Btw: Pandoc is [well documented](https://pandoc.org/) and you can get a list with all the options by calling `pandoc --help` and a lot of explanation by calling `man pandoc`, even when you are offline...

Comment: I upgraded my pandoc. Now, your solution works.