# Adding raster images to a document increases the output size unproportionally

Tags: graphics, pdf, ps, file-size

I have a document which under normal conditions compiles into a reasonably-sized output - 1 MB PDF and 2 MB PS.  I need to add two raster images, also reasonably-sized - About 150 KB JPG each.

I tried the simple approach, and converted the images to PDF and PS.  The graphical results are excellent, but the output grew in size to 2 MB PDF and 8 MB PS (!).

What is the best strategy for converting and including these images in the document, that will not blow up the size of the output significantly?  Ideally, I prefer to have both a DVI->PS output and PDF output, but only the PDF is a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jpeg2ps` utility to convert JPEG images to EPS format. It does not uncompress the images.

Comment: http://www.pdflib.com/download/free-software/jpeg2ps/

Comment: It might be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/convert-gif-image-to-png-on-the-fly/7913#7913), but for conversion use this command:

```
`convert -compress zip #1 eps2:-
```

It requires ImageMagick's `convert`.