# On Ubuntu 10.10 with texlive-full installed, xelatex is rotating my figures 90 degrees counterclockwise

Tags: graphics, xetex, texlive, ubuntu

I am using the latest ubuntu with the texlive-full package. When I do a simple `\includegraphics` like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \rotatebox{-90}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{problem1}}
  \label{fig:prob1}
\end{figure}
```

if I don't include the `\rotatebox` command, my figures are rotated 90 deg. counterclockwise. Additionally, I get this warning:

```
** WARNING ** << /Rotate 90 >> found. (Not supported yet)
```

when rendering using XeLaTeX.

It seems like I have the same problem as this bloke:
http://www.mail-archive.com/xetex@tug.org/msg01532.html

Is there a fix? This does not happen on my other (older) Ubuntu.

Comment: What's important here is the version of XeTeX you have. Could you post the 'banner' line it prints at the start of a run? (Ubuntu tends to be behind the 'standard' TeX Live release schedule. TeX Live 2010 is current, but I think Ubuntu only has TeX Live 2009 with an older XeTeX version.)

Comment: How are you generating your images, and in which format are they?

Comment: Images are in eps, generating them in R. In the evince reader, they seem to have the correct orientation.

Comment: My xetex banner is This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

Comment: do you have a driver specified for graphicx?

Comment: That [ /Rotate 90 ] is inside your file and i believe it's ok (you can find it having opened graphics file with `vim`, let's say). The problem is with xelatex's driver, i guess. Sorry, i can't help you here.

Comment: @brownian: I think what you wrote here is worth being expanded to an answer (with a bit of explanation perhaps).

Comment: @stevejb. Perhaps we might have a link to a demonstration graphics file? I have no problem rotating with XeLaTeX with examples at my disposal (and TeX Live 2010).

Comment: @Joseph Sure, I will post a link to an example file tonight.

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/sj_badRotate/badrotate.zip  That has everything needed, and a pdf showing the problem I am having.

Comment: @stevejb. First, I see that your image is rotated by 90 degrees: this shows up if I open it in GhostView. Second, for me with TeX Live 2010 on Mac I get no warnings. The diagrams are at different angles, but in light of my first point that's what I'd expect.

Comment: @stevejb: i've updated my "answer", please take a look.

Comment: I don't think this is a XeTeX problem. At least I get the same result with pdflatex and with latex > dvips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, i have no answer, but i believe i can give you some hints.

As i said in comment, i guess that your eps graphics files do have that "`/Rotate 90`" commands inside, and it's quite ok. You can check this using this command:

```
grep "Rotate 90" graphics.eps
```

(just replace "`graphics.eps`" with your image file name)

So, i think that the problem is with XeLaTeX's graphics driver. I can not check this, i have no such images around me.

Anyway, i would try to "re-eps" such images with [eps2eps](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/eps2eps1.html); it claims it "performs the equivalent optimization for Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) files".

Not sure that this can help, though.

---

**Update**

I've edited your EPS file (using `vim`), please see the difference:

```
 %%+ font Helvetica-Oblique
 %%+ font Helvetica-BoldOblique
 %%+ font Symbol
-%%DocumentMedia: letter 612 792 0 () ()
+%%DocumentMedia: letter 792 612 0 () ()
 %%Title: R Graphics Output
 %%Creator: R Software
 %%Pages: (atend)
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
 %%BoundingBox: 54 144 558 648
 %%EndComments
 %%BeginProlog
-/bp  { gs 612.00 0 translate 90 rotate gs } def
+/bp  { gs 0 0 translate 0 rotate gs } def
 % begin .ps.prolog
 /gs  { gsave } def
 /gr  { grestore } def
```

Here is the result -- achieved with LaTeX, not XeLaTeX (!!):

[image]

So, this is not a *solution* really, but rather a demonstration (i could find "better" numbers, possibly). So, i do believe that [xe]latex can not display you eps graphic files. Yes, i've tried with `eps2eps` with no success. Oh, well, i've replaced `\usepackage{Sweave}` with `\usepackage{graphicx}`, i hope it didn't any difference.

With XeLaTeX result is just the same with my texlive (2009-7, current Ubuntu's one, i believe).

Well, this is very attractive .)

---

**Update 2**

```
inkscape --export-eps=hist50-good.eps hist50.eps
```

This produces "good" EPS (4678 source expanded to file 78626 bytes long! but quite usable, i'd say).

```
inkscape --export-text-to-path --export-eps=hist50-good.eps hist50.eps
```

This reduses size to 40435 bytes.

As a result, correct page produced.

I think you can process all EPS files in a batch (be sure to make a backup,)

I am still not sure that this can be a solution for you.

ps. i feel like it's a bug?.. Your images are quite good, at least `gv` (3.6.8 here) and `inkscape` (0.47 r22583 here) shows them right.

Comment: I just checked for the string Rotate in all my eps files. Nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I suppose what I can do is just write a script which batch processes unprocessed eps files before xelatex gets called. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: so do you think this is a bug in xelatex for handling certain flags in the eps images? I bet the same would not happen for, say, pngs. I suppose the immediate solution is just to use some other format, although eps would be nice.

Comment: You can declare graphics rule to process on the fly: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/convert-gif-image-to-png-on-the-fly/7913#7913)

Comment: @stevejb: no, not xelatex, because of having the same result with latex->dvips, pdflatex etc. Yes, that what i wrote means that i claim that there is a bug somewhere in "latex core" -- i don't know actually, i am not professional enough for that. But your images are **correct** (from both `gv`'s and `inkscape`'s perspective).

Answer (score 2):

I also don't really have an anwer, I just want to confirm that the problem still exists - and I would call it a *problem*, if pdflatex and xelatex do not produce the same results, ie. one rotates a figure and the other one does not .. It is definitely problem for me, because I share documents with others and some would compile it with pdflatex and others with xelatex..

I have encountered the problem first now, with a pdf produced by Adobe Acrobat - so I have no eps to fix. Interestingly, the same problem exists with TeXLive 2009 on linux and MikTeX 2.9 on Windows, so it really is xelatex issue..

As for solutions, one thing I did was to use gsview, convert the pdf to eps and then back to pdf - the resulting file is almost 3x bigger, but works with both engines.

An alternative would be using `\ifxetex{\rotatebox{-90}{--}}` for the affected figures - not elegant and possibly also not future-proof, assuming xelatex will be fixed at some point..

Or does anyone has a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with R, it might be you have forgotten to `setEPS()` before `postscript('...')`.

I had the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Fixed it with the program I was using to generate the original EPS. I was working with R and added a `horizontal=FALSE` inside `postscript()`. My suggestion is to find a similar option. You don't want to rasterize the image. It defeats the purpose of using EPS.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are creating the EPS from `gnuplot`, if so use

```
set terminal postscript enhanced eps
```

and your EPS and converted will have the correct orientation when included in the document.

(source: http://mathewpeet.org/howto/rotate-postscript/)