# Include Adobe Illustrator files (ai) with XeTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf, illustrator

Adobe Illustrator files are PDF compatible. That is a regular PDF reader, ex. Sumatra-pdf, can open and view them. I was hoping it would be possible to have xetex (with xelatex) and `graphicx` to include Adobe Illustrator files directly without having to go into Illustrator and save as a PDF manually. This would simplify my workflow and make it much quicker to make changes to figures in Illustrator and then compile the xetex document to see how it looks in the text.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

What versions of PDF are supported (is this determined by the `graphicx` package)? Are there other PDF importing methods?

Edit: in the `.log` there isn't much information:

```
File: image.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)
 <use  "image.pdf" >
```

I renamed it to `.pdf` from `.ai`, otherwise it won't work at all, however, the image doesn't appear in the document.

Edit 2: Here is an .ai file from the latest illustrator version (CS5) if anyone wants to play around:
*link removed*

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it may be possible to trick XeTeX into accepting .ai-files from Illustrator I would recommend against it. The in the .ai-file embedded pdf document is using a higher pdf version than the standard version of pdfTeX in most distributions but you can adjust this using `\pdfminoversion`. Additionally the file is much larger and I am not sure if XeTeX would be able to throw out the unnecessary parts, so that your final document would also wasting lots of space.

Exporting it from Illustrator as a PDF/X files has worked nicely for me with many documents and helps you to achieve a final document which is close to PDF/X and won't give you any troubles with printing or different readers.

Comment: Couldn't you just compile against a newer version of PDF then? I know aiming at old versions increase compatibility, but 1.5 came out in 2003. Won't everyone want to move to 1.7 (allows OpenType font embedding) at some point anyway?

Comment: @Canageek: What do you mean by "compiling against a newer version of PDF"? As far as I know pdf-/Xe-/LuaTeX need to understand the embedded pdf file to some degree and do not insert it as a binary blob but I did not find any more information easily.

Comment: PDFTeX defaults to v1.5 of the PDF standard. You can however change this to a higher version via \pdfminorversion according to the PDFTeX manual. It uses 1.5 as a balance between compatibility and features (1.5 adds object compression)

Comment: Sorry, this is bogus. pdfTeX and LuaTeX can include any version of PDF. The _complain_ you get is probably caused by not using `\pdfminorversion`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Thanks for the notice. I changed the comment accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

Just try the following lines. It tells Latex to treat files with .ai extensions like pdf files. My ai file calendar.ai was created with Adobe Illustrator CS3 and is PDF-1.5.

**Update:** I did a mistake. I tested it with pdflatex and lualatex not with xelatex. With xelatex it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.ai}{pdf}{.ai}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{calendar.ai}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you (or the OP) post a link to a file that we can use to test this out?

Comment: Here is a ai file from the latest Illustrator CS5. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/example.ai

Comment: I tested it with the example.ai with the same results: pdflatex and lualatex works, xelatex doesn't work. But if I rename the extension from .ai to .pdf xetex works fine. Example.ai was created by Illustrator CS5 but is PDF-1.5 too.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is no usable error message. Please be more precise. Does the computer explode?

Comment: Thank you, works great with my pdf-compatible ai files created by Illustrator CS6 and Overleaf

Comment: This still seems to not work for xelatex — does that accord with others' outcomes? Any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

I would try to use `inkscape` to convert `ai` to `pdf` -- something like this:

`inkscape --export-pdf=file.pdf file.ai`

If it'd succeed (it should, but "it may depend"), I would try to write a graphics rule, see here, for example: [Convert gif image to png on the fly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/convert-gif-image-to-png-on-the-fly/7913#7913).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

With the example file provided by s0rce, I get the same result in pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX by doing the following trick:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{.ai}{QTm}{QTm}{#1}
\else
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{.ai}{pdf}{.ai}{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example.ai}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

*Note*. The line `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.ai}{QTm}{QTm}{#1}` has been kindly suggested by David Carlisle instead of the more complicated

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{Gin@rule@.ai}#1{{QTm}{QTm}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: why the `\@namedef ` rather than `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.ai}{QTm}{QTm}{#1}` ?

Comment: Just because I copied directly from `xetex.def`

Comment: @egreg Your trick doesn't work for me. If I compile with XeLaTeX I get the error message "Unable to load picture or PDF file 'example.ai'". With pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX it works fine. I use the XeTeX version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (MiKTeX 2.9). What is wrong with my XeLaTeX?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Might be a problem with the QuickTime libraries; I ran the file on Mac OS X.

Comment: I guess this requires quicktime. Is there some F/OSS alternative?