# Insert GIF in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, convert, gif

I'd like to insert a GIF image in my text and I found this [Convert GIF image to PNG on the fly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/convert-gif-image-to-png-on-the-fly).

So I pasted in my document

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.JPG}{eps}{.JPG}{`convert #1 eps:-}
\begin{document}
\framebox{\includegraphics[0,0][150,200]{DSC00121-SMALL.JPG}}
\end{document}
```

Namely I have

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.JPG}{eps}{.JPG}{`convert #1 eps:-}
```

and then

```
 \framebox{\includegraphics[0,0][150,200]{nn.JPG}}
```

Also I have renamed the picture as `nn.JPG`

But it doesn't work! Any help?

Comment: Includegraphics command has a single optional argument (in [ ] ), with possibly several comma separated key=value pairs. Hence your syntax is wrong. For a bitmap you could have to provide the bunding box, but for an eps (even if created on the fly) it is read from the file. Try
`\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{small.gif}` .

Comment: By the way I assume that you have defined the graphicsrule for gif and not only for jpg. Of course renaming .gif to .jpg can not work, as their format is quite different.

Comment: @Jhor Thanks for answering! I tried \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{small.gif} but it doesn't work either. It says "unknown graphics extention .gif"

Comment: @Jhor I have renamed the picture small.gif

Comment: As said in my second comment, you need to replicate the `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.JPG}{eps}{.JPG}{`convert #1 eps:-}` into a gif version.

Comment: @Jhor I'd  appreciate it if you could show me how to do this.

Comment: Which motor are you using (LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeTeX ??)

Comment: @Jhor I do it in overleaf.com where can I find the motor that I use?

Comment: look at the first lines of your .log file

Comment: @Jhor I think it is in  pdfLaTeX

Comment: @Jhor Thank you very much! I actually solved my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the MWE for pdfLaTeX, assuming that you have the command line `convert` from [Image Magick](https://imagemagick.org/) installed, and using the `.png` route, as `pdfLaTeX` already has the method for PNG:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% loading epstopdf package might be needed, 
% but is often automatically loaded by graphicx when running pdfLaTeX
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
% epstopdf setup for GIF
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{%
  \noexpand\epstopdfcall{convert #1 \noexpand\OutputFile}%
}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{This is a GIF version}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{tmp.gif}
% The GIF file is converted to tmp-gif-converted-to.png
\subsection*{This is a jpg version}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{tmp.jpg}
\subsection*{This is a png version}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{tmp.png}
\subsection*{This is a pdf version}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{tmp}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
With old fashioned LaTeX (in dvi mode) one would have to convert GIFs to EPS.
For this purpose, one can replace the `\DeclareGraphicsRule` above by the following one:

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{eps}{.gif.bb}{`convert #1 eps:-}
```

Then the conversion command is written verbatim in the `.dvi` file, and executed by `dvips` provided it is run with the `-R0` option. Finally the PDF file can be produced by using `ps2pdf`.

However, this method has several drawbacks:

- the converted figures are huge;
- it does not work with `dvipdfm(x)`.
- it works only if the `.gif.bb` file has been created,  that can be done with a command like:
  `identify tmp.gif |sed -r -e "s/(.*)\s+([0-9]{2,})x([0-9]{2,})\s+(.*)/%%BoundingBox: 0 0 \2 \3/" > tmp.gif.bb`

for each graphic file `tmp.gif`.

In this context, it becomes much more efficient to write a batch to perform the conversion of all the files outside of `LaTeX/dvips`, by using `convert` with suitable options, or `Netpbm`, or `Irfanview` (windows only) and so on.

**EDIT 2:** On Windows, the `convert` command is a disk handling tool, and recent versions of ImageMagick use `imagemagick convert` (with the space) instead of the bare `convert`. Then `\epstopdfcall` must be modified accordingly.

Comment: Your minimal example gives: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \AppendGraphicsExtensions`. I had to add `\usepackage{grfext}` for it to work.

Comment: @Thomas. Actually `\AppendGraphicsExtensions` is defined in `grfext` package. The latter is automatically loaded by `epstopdf` package. Hence if this package is not automatically loaded via the .cfg file or your pdftex (system dependant), you have to load it, or load `grfext` as you did.