# Why are .gif files not supported?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, animate, gif

This is a question that I have been asking myself for a while and I have not found an answer.

Is it because of licensing issues? Because of the file format? Some other reason?

Comment: Because .gif is a strange collection of many formats and no one bothered building support for it into pdfLaTeX (would have to be done similar to how png is handled, because, afaik, gif can't be directly put into the pdf unlike some other image formats).

Comment: There are some related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475948/82917 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7602/82917https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5396/82917

Comment: jpg and pdf can be fairly easily embedded in pdf gif can not. Nor can png but at least png is just a single bitmap that can be converted to a pdf bitmap converting gif to a video format embeddable in pdf is tricky (and has changed over time as video in pdf support has been somewhat variable) so is much better left to an external program.

Comment: Wasn't gif also covered by patents for many years?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle iirc, gif was original just a container format, and the animated gifs were added to that, so gif can also be "just a single bitmap", but doesn't have to. Handling gif correctly seems much more complicated :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to prove the opposite: Direct embedding GIF ***is*** possible, admittedly not in PDF, yet in SVG output.

We just have to add a `graphicx` rule that treats GIF (static/animated) as another bitmap format (besides PNG and JPEG) with a user-provided `<img file base name>.xbb` file containing the bounding box information:

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{bitmap}{.xbb}{}
```

For a 480px * 360px image, the contents of the `xbb` file reads

```
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 480 360
```

For in-lining GIF data into the SVG output, the GIF file must be base64 encoded. Package `media4svg` provides a command for this that we make use of to modify the `graphicx` driver code for bitmaps (`\Ginclude@bitmap`).

---

(Requires pkg `media4svg`, v0.9 2022-08-12.)

Typeset `example.tex` listed below with

```sh
dvilualatex example
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2 example
```

or

```sh
latex --shell-escape example
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2 example
```

or even

```sh
xelatex --shell-escape --no-pdf example
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2 example.xdv
```

---

**N.B.** Firefox fails to play animated GIF embedded in SVG that is itself embedded in a web page (like TeX.SX). It looks like a bug. Use a Blink-based web browser instead, such as Chromium, Chrome, Opera or Edge. Or (right-)click on the image to open the SVG in a browser tab of its own. [image]

---

Input file `example.tex`.

(Download GIF from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif)

```latex
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{article}

% download `Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif' before typesetting:
%
% https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{bitmap}{.xbb}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% provide BoundingBox information in a separate .xbb file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.xbb}
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 480 360
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% patch graphics backend driver `dvisvgm.def' to physically embed
% bitmaps into DVI
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\let\Ginclude@bitmapOrig\Ginclude@bitmap
\def\Ginclude@bitmap#1{%
  \baseSixtyFour{#1}{72}{{?nl}}\bitmap@stream%
  \Ginclude@bitmapOrig{%
    data:image/\expandafter\remove@dot\Gin@ext;;base64,{?nl}%
    \bitmap@stream}%
}
\def\remove@dot.#1;{#1}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage{media4svg} % provides base64-encode utility
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\baseSixtyFour#1#2#3#4{
  \sys_if_engine_luatex:TF{
    \xdef#4{\directlua{media4svg.base64("#1",#2,"#3")}}
  }{
    \msvg_convert_file_to_blob:nnnN{#1}{#2}{#3}#4
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section{Animated GIF}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an article in [TUGboat](https://www.tug.org/tugboat/) from 1996 (written by by Keith Reckdahl) that includes a discussion of supporting image formats. The article is from Volume 17 No. 1 and is called [Using EPS Graphics in LATEX2ε Documents Part 1](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-1/tb50reck.pdf). The discussion is centered around `dvips`, but a similar argument can be made for direct pdf output (see [David's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580499/why-are-gif-files-not-supported#comment1460429_580499) on this question). Also the historical practise of not implementing direct support in `dvips` may have influenced choices made for `pdflatex` and later compilers.

Quote (page 52-53):

> **10.3  Including Non-EPS Graphic Files**
>
> While it is easy to insert EPS graphics into LATEX documents, it is not as straightforward to insert
> non-EPS graphics (GIF, TIFF, JPEG, PICT, etc.).
>
> [...]
>
> **10.3.1  Direct Support for Non-EPS Graphics**
>
> It is often requested that LATEX and dvips support the direct inclusion of non-EPS graphic
> formats, making it as easy as inserting EPS files. While this would be
> convenient, there unfortunately are some problems which complicate
> things.
>
> For example, most non-EPS graphic formats use binary files
> which cannot be read by TEX, which prevents LATEX from determining the
> size of the non-EPS graphics. Furthermore, supporting non-EPS graphics
> would also require dvips to incorporate graphics conversion
> capabilities (GIF-to-PS, TIFF-to-PS, etc.). This would not only
> require a lot of programming, it would also require more maintenance
> in the future.
>
> Rather than directly incorporating graphics conversion
> routines, dvips provides a mechanism of calling external conversion
> programs. This mechanism can be accessed from LATEX by use [of] the
> command argument of \DeclareGraphicsRule. This has the benefit of being
> more flexible than direct support, and since it keeps the graphics
> conversion uncoupled from the DVI-to-PS conversion, users are free to
> choose their own graphics conversion program.

Another interesting historical approach is described in an [article from 1991](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb12-3-4/tb33sowa.pdf), where photos in GIF format are converted into a font (!) for direct inclusion into LaTeX documents.