# What is the best procedure for integrating .gif?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, animate, gif

I have tried several solutions

- convert with Magick to .png and use the animate package.
- convert to video.

Neither satisfies me. How do you do?

Comment: You are talking about animated GIFs, then? Because .gif, at it's heart, is just an image format.

Comment: Hmm... https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/obsolete-using-media9-to-include-video-and-audio-files/yvdwwvpknjkk

Comment: One option is to have SVG output: https://ctan.org/pkg/media4svg?lang=en (never tried though)

Comment: @Rmano For embedding GIF in SVG, `media4svg` is only indirectly needed. With a suitable driver, [`\includegraphics`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580847) will do.

Comment: @rpapa What are you not satisfied with in particular? Note that since GIF is not supported by the PDF standard, there is no way around conversion to a different image format.