# Import a gif in LaTeX?

Tags: import, gif

Is it possible to add a gif into latex?
I tried it with the same packages of picture format, but it is not working.

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/convert-gif-image-to-png-on-the-fly if you want to convert the gif automatically instead of converting it yourself.

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240243/getting-gif-and-or-moving-images-into-a-latex-presentation if you have an animated gif.